# Pass a Directory Query to <cfzip>?

Tags: zip, coldfusion-9, cfdirectory, cfzip

I need to zip files from a directory, but not *all* the files in the directory. I determine the files that need to be zipped by running a query on the directory listing.

Currently, I'm looping over the query results to add each file to the archive individually, but this can take a while in a large directory.

Is there any way to do this outside of a loop? I couldn't find anything in the CF docs that would indicate that you can pass some sort of list to `cfzip`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately, no. You can pass it an entire directory to zip up, but not a query of files.

Comment: Appreciate it - I found that it was faster to copy the files to a temp directory and then zip that directory rather than calling `cfzip` 100+ times in a loop. Still, would have been nice to pass the list directly...